# Is there a way to build custom error message for default model binding errors, want to get rid of line and position in the message

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

```
{
    "errors": {
        "price": [
            "Could not convert string to decimal: dasdfasdf. Path 'price', line 3, position 22."
        ],
        "userId": [
            "Could not convert string to integer: hsad. Path 'userId', line 6, position 27."
        ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|bcaa98d957e1c04181000489a0bc4950.9753735a_"
}
```

I tried custom model binder, but I need this for specific properties in a model. I also tried the JsonConvert with the property but couldn't find a way to inject the error message in the model state

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the ApiController's ModelState validator response by configuring `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` of `ApiBehaviorOptions` like this:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext => 
    {
        var errors = actionContext.ModelState
            .Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
            .Select(e => new Error
            {
            Name = e.Key,
            Message = e.Value.Errors.First().ErrorMessage
            }).ToArray();

        return new BadRequestObjectResult(errors);
    }
});
```

Also, you can read more about ApiController behaviors [here](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/02/exploring-the-apicontrollerattribute-and-its-features-for-asp-net-core-mvc-2-1/).

Comment: I added this in the startup but it is not getting invoked, still returns a response with default model binding error message.

Comment: How do you want the response to be displayed exactly? @LalitKumarNaidu

Comment: {
    "errors": {
        "price": [
            "Invalid input could not convert to decimal: dasdfasdf."
        ],
        "userId": [
            "Invalid input could not convert to integer: hsad."
        ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|bcaa98d957e1c04181000489a0bc4950.9753735a_"
}

Comment: I don't realize what you want exactly, this is the same as the first response that you've sent, except that it doesn't have any line breaks and tabs. Is that what you want ? @LalitKumarNaidu

Comment: so my requirement is to have a custom message instead of default error messages and not to modify the modelstate response structure

Comment: To just modify the `Error messages` you can pass your custom message to the Data Annotation that you use to validate, like `[Required("Custom message")]` attribute. Also, you can use [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) instead of Data Annotations. @LalitKumarNaidu

Comment: both of these do not work if the string or value supplied in the request are invalid.. binder tries to convert them and responds even before it reaches the validation stage..